# ipython notebook converting to pdf with indent when starting a new paragraph

Tags: html, css, pdf, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I don't want to indent, it looks ugly and not the same as in the notebook. When converting to html, it looks exactly as in notebook, however when converting to pdf, the new paragraph indent about a tab width.

### no indent

[image]

### annoying indent when converting to pdf

[image]

Comment: The latex is generated via pandoc, if you find how to do it through pandoc, it is probably possible to patch nbconvert to use that.

Comment: I guess you can change this with a custom Latex template, but I'm not sure exactly what you'd need to change.

Comment: @ThomasK Oh, see the difference between the above and below figure, the figure below indents when starting a new paragraph.

Comment: Yep, I see it - I mean I don't know exactly what you need to change in the latex to get the result you want.

Comment: You are looking for ``\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`` see e.g. [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_indent_and_break). Note, you will also want ``\parskip``

Answer (score 3):

This is current for nbconvert 4.2.0. It doesn't appear to be using an official API so it seems reasonable to expect this to change between versions. I'll explain the process so that it can hopefully be worked out for future versions too.

By default the PDFs are rendered through latex using the `article.tplx` template. This is found in `<site-packages>\nbconvert\templates\latex` directory. The bit that covers markdown rendering is in `base.tplx`.

So, we create a new template that extends `article.tplx` and copy the bit out of `base.tplx` that covers markdown rendering. In 4.2.0 it started with the line `((* block markdowncell scoped *))`. We add in the couple of commands [Jakob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053372/ipython-notebook-converting-to-pdf-with-indent-when-starting-a-new-paragraph#comment50141307_31053372) suggests above and then use the template to render a PDF from the notebook.

The template file would look like:

```
((= This line inherits from the built in template that you want to use. =))
((* extends 'article.tplx' *))

% Markdown mod. Copied from base.tplx. Parindent & parskip added.
((* block markdowncell scoped *))
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
    ((( cell.source | citation2latex | strip_files_prefix | markdown2latex )))
((* endblock markdowncell *))
```

You then use the custom template with the command:

```
jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to pdf --template my_fixed_indent.tplx
```

Comment: For some reason this approach is cutting off either the last page or last few cells of my notebook.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with nbconvert.  Downloading via the file->download as PDF works, but I can't get the options changed for the default tplx file (https://michaelgoerz.net/notes/custom-template-for-converting-jupyter-notebooks-to-latex.html)